# Update multiple documents by id set. Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I wonder if mongoose has some method to update multiple documents by id set. For example:

```
for (var i = 0, l = ids.length; i < l; i++) {
    Element.update({'_id': ids[i]}, {'visibility': visibility} ,function(err, records){
        if (err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        };
    });
};
```

What i want to know, that if mongoose can do something like this:

```
Element.update({'_id': ids}, {'visibility': visibility}, {multi: true} ,function(err, records){
    if (err) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

where ids is an array of ids, like ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'] - sample array.
Same question for find.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Most probably yes. And it is called using [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator in mongodb query for update.

```
db.Element.update(
   { _id: { $in: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'] } },
   { $set: { visibility : yourvisibility } },
   {multi: true}
)
```

All you need is to find how to implement $in in mongoose.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the $in operator works perfect for mongoose too.

Comment: Can I use multi update but with save command? because with save I have also validation

Comment: Is it possible to update visibility property differently for different _id values ?

Comment: Using {multi: true} query you will able to update visibility property differently for different _id values @Vinay

Comment: This worked for me, using mongoose.
```
Product.update({store: {$in: [storeId]}}, {$set: {disabled: true}}).then(ret => {
console.log(ret);
});
```

Comment: For me its updating first value in $in

Comment: @Santhoshkumar, From what I understand, `{multi: true}` is just to map all the matching values, not just the first matching value. It can't be used to update if each of the `_id` has a different `visibility` value. Can you please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 19):

in **updateMany** function no need of  **{ multi: true }**

```
db.collectionName.updateMany(
    {
        _id:
            {
                $in:
                    [
                        ObjectId("your object id"),
                        ObjectId("your object id")

                    ]
            }
    },
    {
        $inc: { quantity: 100 }

    })
```

I want to add one more point, you can use **$in** to fetch multiple document

```
 db.collectionName.find(
        {
            _id:
                {
                    $in:
                        [
                            ObjectId("your object id"),
                            ObjectId("your object id")

                        ]
                }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Updates all documents that match the specified filter for a collection.

```
let ids = ["kwwe232244h3j44jg3h4", "23h2u32g2h3b3hbh", "fhfu3h4h34u35"];
let visibility = true;

Element.updateMany({_id: {$in: ids}}, 
   { $set: { visibility } }, 
   {multi: true} ,
   function(err, records){
       if (err) {
           return false;
       }
});
```

[know more](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)