# Update multiple embedded documents in multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update multiple embedded documents in multiple documents in MongoDB using mongoose in nodejs.

An example of the document is shown below.

As you can see, in a *'exampleDocument'* there is an embedded document: *'embededDoc'*.

```
let exampleDocument =  
    {   
        _id: '1aa',
        player_id: '9pp',
        docUpdated: false',
        embededDoc:
        [ 
            { 
            _id: '3eb',
            embededDocUpdated: false,
            timeDocWasSaved: '2019-04-30T08:45:50.349Z' 
            } 
        ],
    }
```

How can I update multiple embedded *'embededDoc'* documents in multiple *'exampleDocument'* documents.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096885/update-multiple-documents-by-id-set-mongoose) I know how to update multiple documents with a single command like you can see below:

```
db.exampleDocument.update(
   { _id: { $in: ['1aa', '2bb', '3cc'] } },
   { $set: { docUpdated : yes } }
)
```

What if I wanted to update several embeded documents(*embededDoc*) by their ids?

For example assuming we have three '*exampleDocument*' documents with the ids: '1aa', '2bb', '3cc'. And each of these documents has five embeded documents and I wanted to update some of the embeded documents by their ids... is it possible to do it with one command or will I have to do it document by document?

If possible I would really appreciate a code example with the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use filtered positional update operater `$[elem]`, Try below solution, i have tested it with some sample documents given below:

**Solution:**

```
    db.test.update({
        _id: { 
            $in: ['1aa', '1bb', '1cc'] 
        }
    }, {
        $set: {
            "embededDoc.$[elem].embededDocUpdated": true,
            "docUpdated" : "yes"
        }
    }, { arrayFilters: [{"elem._id": {$in: ['3ed',"3eg","3eb","3eh"]}}], multi: true})
```

**i have tested above query with below sample Documents and its working fine as you want:**

```
    [{
        "_id" : "1cc",
        "player_id" : "9pp",
        "docUpdated" : false,
        "embededDoc" : [
            {
                "_id" : "3ed",
                "embededDocUpdated" : false,
                "timeDocWasSaved" : "2019-04-30T08:45:50.349Z"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "3eh",
                "embededDocUpdated" : false,
                "timeDocWasSaved" : "2019-04-30T08:45:50.349Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "1bb",
        "player_id" : "9pp",
        "docUpdated" : false,
        "embededDoc" : [
            {
                "_id" : "3ec",
                "embededDocUpdated" : false,
                "timeDocWasSaved" : "2019-04-30T08:45:50.349Z"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "3eg",
                "embededDocUpdated" : false,
                "timeDocWasSaved" : "2019-04-30T08:45:50.349Z",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "1aa",
        "player_id" : "9pp",
        "docUpdated" : false,
        "embededDoc" : [
            {
                "_id" : "3eb",
                "embededDocUpdated" : false,
                "timeDocWasSaved" : "2019-04-30T08:45:50.349Z",
            },
            {
                "_id" : "3ef",
                "embededDocUpdated" : false,
                "timeDocWasSaved" : "2019-04-30T08:45:50.349Z"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: Just tested it in the mongoDB terminal... It works like a charm... Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey :) kindly check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670212/mongodb-how-to-insert-an-embedded-document-in-an-array-if-a-certain-field-is-u). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
db.collection.update(
{ "embededDoc._id": "3eb" },
{ $set: { "embededDoc.$.embededDocUpdated" :true  } }
)
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer the question. I am trying to updated multiple nested documents found in multiple documents.

Comment: Can you provide a correct document for this ? Are you trying to update `embededDocUpdated `  for all documents in the where condition ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to update embeddedDocUpdated but not all of them I am trying to update them by their ids...

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: One update query can take only match query to update document. you can specify `multi: true` if there are multiple documents satisfying the match query, this will update all documents matching the query given in update function.

Comment: What does the dollar sign in : *"embededDoc.$.embededDocUpdated" :true* mean?

Comment: If you eant to updame multiple, you can use `updateMany`.
`$` is array update operators
`https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/`