# Updating Multiple Documents In MongoDB Based on ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I've seen this question asked before, but when I tried the solution myself it didn't seem to work. [Update multiple documents by id set. Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096885/update-multiple-documents-by-id-set-mongoose)

Based on the solution above, I wrote this code:

```
listOfParticipant = [ "5f50a1df63fe0000ed98b393", "5f69cc7cda1d549f9edcc8bb","5f3207204450b32620449657","5f3207204450b32620449657", "5f39585030027a3d57f0cc0e", "5e719e4715c7865bcb00c820", "5f32d0ab59eccf22d2e2f29f" ],
    
    User.update( {_id: {$in: listOfParticipant}},
              {$addToSet: {
                userNotification: notification
              }
            },
            {multi: true}
            )
```

But it doesn't seem to work, could anyone help me out in finding out why?

Comment: Your query is valid. Try it on this MongoPlayground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/_DomGr_F3wB

Answer (score 0):

So this query is correct. The reason it wasn't working is because I was trying to chain it with another MongoDB call. I was trying to use it inside the callback function when I updated another MongoDB collection. Once I made this into its own separate function, it worked just fine!